# A special example environment

Tags: page-breaking, environments, framed, examples

How can I define an environment named "example" so that:

1. can be broken over pages
2. has a horizontal line above "Example \chap.\no" (e.g. Example 4.10),
   and vertical line that is spread to the whole content of the example
   and ends to a square symbol close to the text or formula
3. tables, figures, and other floats can be inserted in the environment
4. the last line of this environment can be text or formula; If it is a
   formula, the square symbol (QED) should be inserted close to it (the
   same but not the next line)
5. has a bold horizontal line above "Example 4.8". The line has to be as long as "Example 4.8" length; so it should not have a fixed length.
6. the bottom horizontal line should come to near of the rightmost word at the last line. For example, in the image below, the rightmost word at the last line, is "`5685.`", so we want to draw the bottom horizontal line (and consequently the QED symbol), just near to this word.

Just like the following image

**EDIT: conditions 5 and 6 added**
[image]

Comment: [The `mdframed` package](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/mdframed) would certainly help here.

Comment: It has serious flaws. for example, floats (figures, ...) can not be inserted in a 'mdframed' environment

Comment: @smh It is true that `floats` can not go in  `mdframed` environments, but I wouldn't say that it has 'serious flaws'. It does more than any other framing package available. Putting a `float` in a `frame` is very trick- putting a `frame` in a `float` is much easier

Comment: I don't think it makes sense to put a float into a framed environment, if latex floated the table what would you do with the frame? simply use a tabular environment with no surrounding table environment (the caption package will let you still use a caption)

Comment: If the "float" is needed just to provide a caption with "Table 1" (or what number is needed), then `\captionof` of the `caption` package is what you're looking for.

Comment: Thanks for your comment. but I need the code to do such work!

Comment: Not there any more idea?

Comment: @smh: Every package that provides frames put the contents inside a box. So you can't use any floats in there. Which other flaws do you know?

Comment: @smh: Is the question solved for you? Can we close the question?

Comment: @MarcoDaniel: No. I picked the image from a book, so there should be a solution to this problem

Comment: I can only provide a solution using mdframed. But you said this package has some flaws. Without specifying the flaws I can't provide a solution.

Comment: @smh To clarify: You want floats to work inside this environment? How and why? What should happen to the frame when the float will be placed two pages after the “official” end of the frame? If you only want to place pictures and tables (e.g. typical float contents) in your environment you can do this without floats (e.g. `center` environment and any `\captionof` macro). On the other hand, I could see a `tikzmark` solution that draws the lines and *maybe* inserts itself into floats so that they get the blue border but there is no warranty that they will be placed inside the environment.

Comment: Since you have some responses below that seem to answer your question, please consider marking one of them as ‘Accepted’ by clicking on the tickmark below their vote count (see [How do you accept an answer?](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1852)). This shows which answer helped you most, and it assigns reputation points to the author of the answer (and to you!). It's part of [this site's idea to identify good questions and answers through upvotes and acceptance of answers](http://tex.stackexchange.com/about).

Answer (score 26):

One possible solution, at least for requests 1, 2 3, and 5, using [`mdframed`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/mdframed):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[a5paper]{geometry}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage[framemethod=tikz]{mdframed}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\newcounter{exa}[section]
\renewcommand\theexa{\thesection.\arabic{exa}}

\newlength\mylen% to hols the width of the title

\newmdenv[
  settings={\global\refstepcounter{exa}
            \settowidth\mylen{\bfseries\color{cyan}Example~\theexa}},
  leftline=false,
  linecolor=cyan,
  middlelinewidth=1pt,
  innertopmargin=30pt,
  innerbottommargin=10pt,
  innerleftmargin=0pt,
  skipbelow=1.3\topsep,
  singleextra={
    \path node[font=\bfseries\color{cyan},anchor=west,yshift=-12pt,inner sep=0pt] at (O|-P) {Example~\theexa};
    \draw[ultra thick,cyan] ([yshift=.5\pgflinewidth]O|-P) -- ++(\mylen,0pt);
    \draw[line width=2pt,white] (O) -- ($(P|-O)+(-2cm,0pt)$) node (A){};
    \node[anchor=south west,fill=cyan,inner sep=3pt,outer sep=0pt] at (A) {};
  },
  firstextra={
    \path node[font=\bfseries\color{cyan},anchor=west,yshift=-12pt,inner sep=0pt] at (O|-P) {Example~\theexa};
    \draw[ultra thick,cyan] ([yshift=.5\pgflinewidth]O|-P) -- ++(\mylen,0pt);
  },
  secondextra={
    \draw[line width=2pt,white] (O) -- ($(P|-O)+(-2cm,0pt)$) node (A){};
    \node[anchor=south west,fill=cyan,inner sep=3pt,outer sep=0pt] at (A) {};
  }
]{example}

\begin{document}

\section{Test Section}
\begin{example}
\lipsum[4]
\begin{center}
\captionof{table}{This is a table inside a \texttt{mdframed} environment}
\begin{tabular}{ccc}
\toprule
column1a & column2a & column3a \\
column1a & column2a & column3a \\
column1a & column2a & column3a \\
\bottomrule
\end{tabular}
\end{center}
\end{example}
\lipsum*[2-3]
\setcounter{exa}{23}% just for the example
\begin{example}
\lipsum*[1-4]
\begin{center}
\includegraphics[width=6cm]{ctanlion}
\captionof{figure}{This is a figure inside a \texttt{mdframed} environment}
\end{center}
\lipsum*[5-6]
\end{example}
\lipsum*[2]

\end{document}
```

[image]

Floats won't be allowed inside the `mdframed` environment; as has been mentioned in comments, this is not a restriction; in fact, it wouldn't make much sense. However, as the example demonstrates, one can still have tabular material and images with captions, using the `\captionof` from the [`caption`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/caption) or [`capt-of`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/capt-of) packages.

CTAN lion drawing by Duane Bibby.

---

**SMH: Due to a reference issue, I edited the code.**

---

Another approach is the suggest package `tcolorbox`. With the newest version of the package you can use the following code. It has the same limitation like `mdframed`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[a5paper]{geometry}
\usepackage{mwe}%load graphix,lipsum,...
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{tcolorbox}
\tcbuselibrary{skins}
\tcbuselibrary{breakable}

\newcounter{example}[section]
\renewcommand\theexample{\thesection.\arabic{example}}

\tcbset{examplebox/.style={%
 title={Example~\refstepcounter{example}\theexample},
 breakable,
 leftrule=0pt,
 arc=0pt,
 colback=white,
 colframe=cyan,
 enhanced,
 colbacktitle=white,
 coltitle=cyan,
 titlerule=0pt,
 enlarge left by=-4mm,
 width=\linewidth+4mm,
 enlarge top by=2pt,
 overlay unbroken={\draw[cyan,line width=2pt] (frame.north west)++(0,0.25mm) --++(4cm,0pt);
                      \draw[white,line width=10mm] (frame.south west) --++(8cm,0pt) node (P) {};
                      \fill[cyan] (P) rectangle ++(6pt,6pt) ;},%
 overlay first={\draw[cyan,line width=2pt] (frame.north west)++(0,1pt) --++(4cm,0pt);},%
 overlay last={\draw[white,line width=10mm] (frame.south west) --++(8cm,0pt) node (P) {};
                       \fill[cyan] (P) rectangle ++(6pt,6pt) ;},%
 }%
}

\newenvironment{example}{%
  \tcolorbox[examplebox]}%
 {\endtcolorbox}

\begin{document}

\section{Test Section}

\begin{example}
\lipsum[4]
\begin{center}
\captionof{table}{This is a table inside a \texttt{tcolorbox} environment}
\begin{tabular}{ccc}
\toprule
column1a & column2a & column3a \\
column1a & column2a & column3a \\
column1a & column2a & column3a \\
\bottomrule
\end{tabular}
\end{center}
\end{example}
\lipsum*[2-3]
\begin{example}
\lipsum*[1-4]
\begin{center}
\includegraphics[width=6cm]{example-image-a}
\captionof{figure}{This is a figure inside a \texttt{tcolorbox} environment}
\end{center}
\lipsum*[5-6]
\end{example}
\lipsum*[2]

\end{document}
```

Comment: +1 but there are two defects on the bottom frame. Please zoom in.

Comment: @Karl'sstudents do you mean the alignment of the little blue square?

Comment: Please see this [screenshot](http://i.stack.imgur.com/xzoeI.png).

Comment: @Karl'sstudents I think now it's fixed, but I'd like to be sure (I can only zoom to 400%). Could you please let me know if there's still a problem with the alignment?

Comment: Great answer :), thank you both. There exists a question: "with this code, we have no choice to place tables and figures on top or bottom of pages. We just put them in the position they are (like [h!] parameter)". How can we define [t] or [b] option for the code?

Comment: @smh I've updated the example with `mdframed` to fulfill requirement 5. (the thick rule will have the same width as the title). I don't understand your description of requirement 6., please explain with a little more detail. Regarding the positioning of figures and tables, I see no easy way in implementing a pseudo-floating mechanism inside the environments, sorry. The solution with `\captionof` at fixed locations is what there is for now.

Comment: @GonzaloMedina Thanks a lot. The condition 6 has been updated.

Comment: I could not finally found a way to solve the issue 6. Any idea?

Answer (score 3):

<sub>I don't like unanswered questions</sub>

**related to request 1:**

Can be done by packages like:

- `mdframed`
- `tcolorbox`

<sub>alphabetical order</sub>

**related to request 2:**

Can be done by packages like:

- `mdframed`
- `tcolorbox`

<sub>alphabetical order</sub>

**related to request 3:**

You can't use floating objects inside frame environments! You can use tables and figures inside such environments. Please note these environments can't be broken by any of the listed packages above.

**related to request 4:**

Maybe it's possible, but I have no idea.